# What is a "differential chemical abundance"?

Tags: stellar-astrophysics, elemental-abundances

Probably this is a extremely basic question, but after a lot of time searching about it without results (in all the sites/publications i've found they only use this term but there is no specific definition)i came here with the hope of get an answer to my question: in the context of chemical abundance in stars, what is a differential abundance?

I already know what is a chemical abundance, the question is simply about the implication of the "differential" word.

Specifically, my doubt emerged when i was reading [this publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09067).
In the second paragraph of the section 3.2 "Stellar Parameters" is the first encounter with this concept:

> We adopted the same line list as in Ramírez et al. (2014). The
>   EW  measurements  were  used  to  obtain  elemental  abundances
>   with the
>   *abfind*
>   driver of MOOG (Sneden 1973), using Kurucz
>   model atmospheres (Castelli & Kurucz 2004). Then, line-by-line
>   differential abundances were obtained.
>
> The stellar parameters
>   $(T_\text{eff}, \log g, {\rm[Fe/H]}, v_t)$
>   of HIP 68468
>   were determined by imposing a differential spectroscopic equilibrium  of  iron  lines  relative  to  the  Sun  (e.g.  Meléndez  et  al.
>   2014a), using as initial parameters the values given in Ramírez
>   et al. (2014). The solar values were kept fixed at
>   $(T_\text{eff}, \log g, v_t)
> = \rm
> (5777\,K, 4.44\,dex, 1.0\,km\,s^{-1})$. Our solution for HIP 68468
>   gives consistent differential abundances for neutral and ionised
>   species of different elements, and also for atomic and molecular
>   lines, as discussed in more detail in the next section.

Answer (score 3):

If the line emission is optically thin, then the measured line flux is proportional to the abundance $F_{\nu} \sim n$ of a species along the line of sight (if it's only one species).

The problem here is that $F_{\nu}$ needs to be measured relative to a baseline. If that fails, e.e. when the stellar signal is too noisy, one doesn't know what this should be. But a measurment at two different wavelengths $\nu$ and $\nu'$ that lie reasonably close together, can at least yield a difference in abundances $F_{\nu}-F_{\nu'} \approx n-n'$ relative to this unknown base level.
This allows then to construct an atmospheric model, up to the unknown base level, which one can try to fix with other physical arguments.